# I need to pick up the inconsistent value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
select term, dial from #archiving where error_code = '308'
```

Results:

```
     term                  dial
  011211928433184        211928433184
    2687176073           12687176073
    2687177729           12687177729
0114317862324b7744      4317862324b7744211
  1.16141E+12             1.16141E+12
```

I need to exclude term which has exact ten digit numbers other than that I need pick up all inconsistent digits in term. In the end it should look like this

```
 term                     dial
011211928433184        211928433184
0114317862324b7744     4317862324b7744211
  1.16141E+12             1.16141E+12
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT term,
      dial
FROM   #archiving
WHERE  error_code = '308'
      AND LEN(CAST(term AS VARCHAR)) <> 10;
```